# Convert street address to coordinates and place in html

Tags: javascript, html, coordinates, street-address

I have the javascript to convert street address to coordinates. But I want is when a user types in an address in an input field, the javascript converts it into lat and lng and places the result in a p div, say below the input field.

The JS code I have is

```
    var latitude;
    var longitude;

    /*
    * Get the json file from Google Geo
    */
    function Convert_LatLng_To_Address(address, callback) {
            url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&sensor=false";
            jQuery.getJSON(url, function (json) {
                Create_Address(json, callback);
            });        
    }

    /*
    * Create an address out of the json    
    */
    function Create_Address(json, callback) {
        if (!check_status(json)) // If the json file's status is not ok, then return
            return 0;
        latitude = json["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"];
        longitude = json["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"];
        callback();
    }

    /* 
    * Check if the json data from Google Geo is valid 
    */
    function check_status(json) {
        if (json["status"] == "OK") return true;
        return false;
    }
       <body>
        Address:
    <input type="text" id="address-input">
    City:
    <input type="text" id="city-input">
    Country:
    <input type="text" id="country-input">
    Postcode:
    <input type="text" id="address4">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="generate" onClick="AlertLatLng()">


    <p id="result"></p>




    <script>

var street_address = document.getElementById('address-input').value,
    city = document.getElementById('city-input').value,
    country = document.getElementById('country-input').value,
    postcode = document.getElementById('postcode-input').value;

var address = street_address + ' ' + city + ' ' + country + ', ' + postcode;

        // AlertLatLng is a callback function which will be executed after converting         address to coordinates
        Convert_LatLng_To_Address(address, AlertLatLng);     

        /*
        * Alert Latitude & Longitude
        */
        function AlertLatLng() {
    var result = "The latitude is " + latitude + " and longitude is " + longitude;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=result;
}
</scrip>
  </body>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use javacsript to set the contents of an DOM element.

Javscript:

```
function AlertLatLng() {
    var result = "The latitude is " + latitude + " and longitude is " + longitude;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=result;
}
```

This is will now place your message into the `<p id='result'>` tags located below your input fields.

**EDIT:**

To pass information from form input fields to javascript you need to grab the value of the input fields (see: [Passing HTML Form Data to Javascript Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547456/passing-html-form-data-to-javascript-function)).  In short:

```
var address = "address+city+country,+postcode"
```

Could be:

```
var street_address = document.getElementById('address1').value,
    city = document.getElementById('address2').value,
    country = document.getElementById('address3').value,
    postcode = document.getElementById('address4').value;
var address =  street_address + ' ' + city + ' ' + country + ', ' + postcode;
```

As a suggestion you may want to use more intuitive `id` attributes for your input tags: `id="city-input"`, `id="postcode-input"`, etc.  It may make your code easier to read.

**EDIT 2:**

As a quick side note..you have misspelled script in the closing tag at the bottom of your code snippet.  Your browser will most likely correct this but it might be worth just taking care of.

As for the next part of your question...

It looks to me like the latitude and longitude variables get defined in `Create_Address`, which is the callback function for the `jQuery.getJSON` call in `Convert_LatLng_To_Address` which makes a call to the google maps api.

Unfortunately, your js code at the bottom which sets the variable `address` is only run once on the page load.  The result of this will be that all the variables will be empty strings or undefined.  You make a single call to `Convert_LatLng_To_Address(address, AlertLatLng)` which is all fine and dandy but you may want to have this happen once you have the information in the form.

The submit action on your form calls `AlertLatLng()` on a click event. There probably should be a call to make a new call to the google maps api with the information that is in the input fields at the time of submission instead of just once.

I would suggest wrapping all the code into a simple function as such

```
function getNewLatLng() {
    var street_address = document.getElementById('address-input').value,
    city = document.getElementById('city-input').value,
    country = document.getElementById('country-input').value,
    postcode = document.getElementById('postcode-input').value;

    var address = street_address + ' ' + city + ' ' + country + ', ' + postcode;

    // AlertLatLng is a callback function which will be executed after converting address to coordinates
    Convert_LatLng_To_Address(address, AlertLatLng);
}
```

and then editing the HTML to run this function instead on the submission:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="generate" onClick="getNewLatLng()">
```

Comment: OK I have edited my code above and it displays the results in the p tag.  What do I have to place in the address variable in order to grab the information from the input fields that the user types in?

Comment: Did that answer your question?

Comment: thanks for your help.  I modified my inputs fields and added the new javascript.  Now when I click the 'generate' button, I get "The latitude is undefined and longitude is undefined."  I am pretty sure this is something to do with the javascript in the head section.  What do you think??

Comment: I played around with the code, and the form did generate some coordinates, however, it showed my location in Spain (I live in the UK).  So I just changed the codes back to the above.

Comment: Did that help at all?

Comment: thank you for your help, farmerjoe (and Olan), however, I decided to just create coordinates from geolocation.  Probably better and more convenient for what I needed.  I did try your edit but can't get it to work :(

Answer (score 0):

As you have jquery already loaded, you can use it:

```
function AlertLatLng() {
    $("p#result").text("The latitude is " + latitude + " and longitude is " + longitude);
}
```

As a sidenote, you should be passing the latitude and longitude vars to your callback() in `Create_Address`.