# Using HTML Forms to pass input data into Javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to use inputs from a HTML form into a Javascript code. The inputs are 3 zip codes and the result is computation of distance between them and it is followed by a simple arithmetic. 
First I created a html form

```
    <form>
*Enter 5 digit US ZipCodes<br><br>
Port ZipCode:<br>
<input type="text" id="PortZip" value="31402">
<br><br>
Importer ZipCode:<br>
<input type="text" id="ImporterZip" value="30308">
<br><br>
Exporter ZipCode:<br>
<input type="text" id="ExporterZip" value="30901">
<br><br>

<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="initialize()" />
</form>
```

Then I passed the 3 zip-codes into JS

```
var zipCodesToLookup1 = new Array('document.getElementById("PortZip").value', 'document.getElementById("ImporterZip").value', 'document.getElementById("ExporterZip").value', 'document.getElementById("PortZip").value');
```

Complete code is below-

```
    <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
*Enter 5 digit US ZipCodes<br><br>
Port ZipCode:<br>
<input type="text" name="PortZip" value="31402">
<br><br>
Importer ZipCode:<br>
<input type="text" name="ImporterZip" value="30308">
<br><br>
Exporter ZipCode:<br>
<input type="text" name="ExporterZip" value="30901">
<br><br>

<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="initialize()" />
</form> 

<div id="zip_code_output"></div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:650px; height:600px;"></div>




<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {

     //INITIALIZE GLOBAL VARIABLES
     var zipCodesToLookup1 = new Array('document.getElementById("PortZip").value', 'document.getElementById("ImporterZip").value', 'document.getElementById("ExporterZip").value', 'document.getElementById("PortZip").value');
     var output           = '<tr><th scope="col">From</th><th scope="col">To</th><th scope="col">Miles</th></tr>';
     var difference = "0";
     var totalDist = 0;
    // document.write(difference);
     //EXECUTE THE DISTANCE MATRIX QUERY
     var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
     service.getDistanceMatrix({
          origins:      zipCodesToLookup1,
          destinations: zipCodesToLookup1,
          travelMode:   google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
          unitSystem:   google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
     }, function(response, status) {
          if(status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
               var origins = response.originAddresses;
               var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
               for(var i=0; i < origins.length-1; i++) {
                     var results = response.rows[i].elements;
                     output += '<tr><td>' + origins[i] + '</td><td>' + destinations[i+1] + '</td><td>' + results[i+1].distance.text + '</td></tr>';
                     if (i != 0){
                     totalDist += results[i+1].distance.value;
                     }
                     else {
                     totalDist -= results[i+1].distance.value;
                     }

               }
              output += '<tr><td></td><td>OUT OF ROUTE DISTANCE -</td><td>'+(totalDist/1000*0.621371).toFixed(0)+ ' mi</td></tr>';


               document.getElementById('zip_code_output').innerHTML = '<table cellpadding="5">' + output + '</table>';
          }
     });
}

//FUNCTION TO LOAD THE GOOGLE MAPS API
function loadScript() {
     var script  = document.createElement("script");
     script.type = "text/javascript";
     script.src  = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCDZpAoR25KSkPTRIvI3MZoAg1NL6f0JV0&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
     document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;

</script>
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The code is not working. I suspect my html form code is not right. Corrections are welcomed.

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: what do you want to do ?

Comment: The code is not working. I suspect my html form code is not right.

Comment: How are you passing the form data to javascript? There is no submit action for the form.

Comment: I tried to code by looking at a similar example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547456/passing-html-form-data-to-javascript-function)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82245/discussion-between-karvy1-and-diwas).

Comment: May I know why my question is still down-voted? @Diwas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dude, you are using document.getElementbyId in javascript. But where is your id in the form? you have given it as name.
Also your array initialization is wrong. You are passing the paramaters as string. 
Modify your code as follows:

The form:

```
<form>
    *Enter 5 digit US ZipCodes<br><br>
    Port ZipCode:<br>
    <input type="text" id="PortZip" value="31402">
    <br><br>
    Importer ZipCode:<br>
    <input type="text" id="ImporterZip" value="30308">
    <br><br>
    Exporter ZipCode:<br>
    <input type="text" id="ExporterZip" value="30901">
    <br><br>

    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="initialize()" />
</form>
```

The javascript:

```
<script>
function initialize() {

            //INITIALIZE GLOBAL VARIABLES
            var zipCodesToLookup1 = new Array(document.getElementById("PortZip").value, document.getElementById("ImporterZip").value, document.getElementById("ExporterZip").value, document.getElementById("PortZip").value);
            var output           = '<tr><th scope="col">From</th><th scope="col">To</th><th scope="col">Miles</th></tr>';
            var difference = "0";
            var totalDist = 0;
            console.log(zipCodesToLookup1);
            // document.write(difference);
            //EXECUTE THE DISTANCE MATRIX QUERY
            var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            service.getDistanceMatrix({
                origins:      zipCodesToLookup1,
                destinations: zipCodesToLookup1,
                travelMode:   google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem:   google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
                }, function(response, status) {
                if(status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                    var origins = response.originAddresses;
                    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
                    for(var i=0; i < origins.length-1; i++) {
                        var results = response.rows[i].elements;
                        output += '<tr><td>' + origins[i] + '</td><td>' + destinations[i+1] + '</td><td>' + results[i+1].distance.text + '</td></tr>';
                        if (i != 0){
                            totalDist += results[i+1].distance.value;
                        }
                        else {
                            totalDist -= results[i+1].distance.value;
                        }

                    }
                    output += '<tr><td></td><td>OUT OF ROUTE DISTANCE -</td><td>'+(totalDist/1000*0.621371).toFixed(0)+ ' mi</td></tr>';


                    document.getElementById('zip_code_output').innerHTML = '<table cellpadding="5">' + output + '</table>';
                }
            });
        }

        //FUNCTION TO LOAD THE GOOGLE MAPS API
        function loadScript() {
            var script  = document.createElement("script");
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            script.src  = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCDZpAoR25KSkPTRIvI3MZoAg1NL6f0JV0&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }

        window.onload = loadScript;

        </script>
```

Add the ids to form element and remove the quotation in array.